# Fixing small Batch file

Tags: file, batch-file

I have files in one folder with the names like

```
John-Smith-014_15616812_5165
Robert-Walker-014_15644812_5145
```

I want these files to be checked and if they matched to the already existed one then automatically moved there.

Destination folders are already created and they look like:

```
John-Smith-156.81.251.452
Robert-Walker-12.108.36.5418
```

I have tried this code:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
pushd "C:\dest"
FOR %%G IN (*) DO (
  FOR /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%a IN ("%%G") do (
    set "outFolder=%%a"
    for /D %%i in (*.*) do (
      for /F "tokens=1 delims=_" %%b IN ("%%i") do (
        if "%%a"=="%%b" set "outFolder=%%i"
      )
    )
    if not exist "!outfolder!" md "!outfolder!"
    move "%%G" "!outfolder!"
  )
)
popd
pause
```

This code partly works but it can't make difference between `Robert-Walker` to `Robert-Brown` and it will move both of them to the folder with the name `Robert-Walker-12.108.36.5418`

In this code it won't check both first and second tokens in order to sort those files according to their name and surname, instead it sorts only by their name.

Comment: I have tried "tokens=1,2 delims=-" too but it put files with the different surname in the same folder and with the hyphenated name I had the same result. "-014" isn't significant.

Comment: You code works for me. Are you sure your inputs are correct? Temporarily add a couple echo statements so you can see what is going on.

Comment: I'm curious as to how exactly this would be working @RGuggisberg when the is no For loop generating a value for the %%i metavariable referenced in the `For "tokens=1 delims=_" %%b` Loop set.

Comment: So you want to move files whose names begin with `John-Smith-` into the sub-directory `John-Smith-156.81.251.452` – is that correct? *N. B.:* Please provide a more specific question title!